# How do i work with ApplicationUser Id As a foreign key to view Products related to him in a view

Tags: asp.net-core

```
   namespace ServExchange.Model

{
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser  
{
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ProfileSummary { get; set; }

    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

Below is the Product Class with the ApplicationUser Id as foreign Key.

```
public class Product      

{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MinQuantity { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

How do I reference the Product to the ApplicationUser in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly query the database in controller and pass the list to view :

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var result= _applicationDbContext.Products.Where(x => x.ApplicationUser.Id == User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)).ToList();
}
```

In `ApplicationDbContext`, add the DbSet and apply migration :

```
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```